# "Date Modified" silently changes

Tags: macos, pages

I have a simple Pages document and **sometimes** when I open and then close it, macOS changes its "Date Modified" value to the current date and time.

The "Date Modified" silently changes even if System Settings has "Ask to keep changes when closing document" enabled.

Why is this?

Edit: I have uploaded both files here: https://easyupload.io/m/gp4kv5

Comment: .pages files are ZIP archives, so even if just some metadata within the archive changes it may lead to a modified ZIP files. But that's hard to say without hard evidence (e.g. by comparing two versions of the same document which should be unchanged).

Comment: @nohillside I have uploaded both files here: https://easyupload.io/m/gp4kv5

Comment: What file system is the document stored on? APFS, or something else? I haven't been able to replicate this, without actually making a change.

Comment: APFS, I suppose. It is a new Macbook Pro with the M1 Pro chip. I don't use any special software or settings.

Comment: All I can see from the files you uploaded is that most the files within the Pages archive got rewritten with a new date/time and that `Index/Metadata.iwa` and `Index/ViewState-1689205.iwa` changed size slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that macOS doesn't endeavor to keep "Date Modified" representative of the last time you made a substantive change to a document. It's simply not a priority.

This means that even just opening the file might cause metadata changes to trigger a "Date Modified" change.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted, but I want to know why exactly this happened and may happen in the future with Pages documents.

Comment: "Date Modified" is set by the OS directly, and always accurate. It doesn't care about "substantial changes", it gets changed as soon as you write one byte to a file.